# React - Where should i call api?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a website which does **`a lot of api calls`**, it is a really big project, when it grew up, i started having some problems with backend's data, **`some components was depending on another components to receive data`**, and i had to create many `if` to check if the data already was loaded to show them. With this situation, i've had some doubts about **good practices**

1. Should i load every data from backend in the very beggining? for
   example in `app.js` file and then pass the data already loaded
   through props?
2. Is it a good practice calling api in useEffect? cause it may delay
   some seconds, it won't be nice to user

Comment: Do a google search before asking question on SO. This is a generic question and has so many blogs on this particular topics. Just search React Api calls hooks gives a ton of blogs and resources about best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have loading states there shouldn't be an issue with fetching data for multiple components progressively throughout your app. Typically I would use a container component where the API call would be made. Then that renders conditionally the loading state or the "dumber" child component that holds and renders the data. Getting data when you need it is probably better than getting all of it and having it when you don't.

This first question feels very opinionated and kinda feels like a case by case basis decision. I want to clarify as well that this is indeed my opinion on this question.

2. Calling API inside of a useEffect is an entirely legitimate use case. For example say you have an infinite scroller that renders on your page. You could have a useEffect make the initial call to the API to get the first set of results.  Regardless, yes this is fine.

```
useEffect(() => {
someAPICallForInitialData();
}, []);

...some code here

<InfiniteScoller onScroll={() => getMoreData()}>
{chidren}
<InfiniteScoller />
```